# Word metric for the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Given a generating set of permutations for the symmetric group $S_n$, how can one find the [word metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric) between two members of $S_n$? Also how can one find the largest distance between all pairs of members?

Currently my best method is a breadth first search.

Comment: It's not easy -- [God's Number](http://cube20.org/), which took decades of computer time to verify, can be phrased as the "largest distance" problem in a particular 6-generator subgroup of $S_{48}$. (And that even had plenty of additional symmetry that was used to speed up the search).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks, I figured there wasn't an elegant way in general but had to make sure.